# Array.map com parseInt retorna resultado inesperado

Tags: javascript

Estava vendo um comentário do jbueno no chat e resolvi testar nos navegadores IE, Firefox e Chrome, ao rodar nos consoles este comando:

```
['10', '10', '10'].map(parseInt);
```

Ele me retornou isto:

> [10, NaN, 2]

Quando o esperado seria isto:

> [10, 10, 10]

Mas se eu fizer assim:

```
['10', '10', '10'].map(function(a) { return parseInt(a); });
```

Ele retorna perfeitamente isto:

> [10, 10, 10]

Eu não entendi porque isto ocorre, mas eu acredito que talvez o `parseInt` trabalhe o array do `map` como referencia, ou seja além do `return` ele modifica a referencia diretamente a cada loop além do `return`, mas não tenho certeza.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quando usas `.map(parseInt);` o que está acontecer é:

```
['10', '10', '10'].map(function(el, index, array) {
    var res = parseInt(el, index);
    return res;
});
```

Ou seja, o `map()` passa mais do que um argumento à callback. O método `.map()` passa 3* argumentos à callback, e o segundo argumento está a ser tratado como radix pelo [`parseInt(str, radix);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Exemplos:

```js
var A = ['10', '10', '10'].map(function(el, index) {
    return parseInt(el, index);
});

var B = ['10', '10', '10'].map(function(el, index) {
    return parseInt(el, 10); // <-- aqui damos o radix como fixo, base 10
});

console.log(A, '|', B); // dá [10, NaN, 2] "|" [10, 10, 10]
```

O `parseInt` permite portanto converter strings em numeros com base octal, decimal, hexadecimal, etc... dependendo do segundo argumento que lhe é atribuído. Esse segundo parâmetro pode ser um inteiro entre 2 e 36. Na ausência de 2o argumento o `parseInt` decide sozinho**, e isso pode levar a erros difíceis de descobrir.

> * - O método [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passa 3 argumentos. O ***elemento da array*** a ser iterado, o ***index*** ou posição que esse elemento tem na Array, e por último a propria ***Array***.
>
> ** - Na maioria das implementações dos browsers a ausência do segundo argumento faz o método assumir base dez.

Comment: É irrelevante neste caso, mas vale lembrar que a callback também recebe a array de origem como terceiro argumento.

Comment: @patetico bem correto. Estava a editar e juntei isso também. Obrigado.