# Qual a diferença de parseInt() e Number()?

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre o `parseInt()`  e `Number()`?

Se utilizar:

```js
console.log(parseInt('100'));
console.log(parseInt('1'));
console.log(parseInt('a'));
```

```js
console.log(Number('100'));
console.log(Number('1'));
console.log(Number('a'));
```

Ambos tem o mesmo resultado, qual seria a diferença e onde essas diferenças seriam aplicadas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eles têm propósitos diferentes, mas podem ser usados para fins comuns.

O `Number` faz conversão de tipo, para *Number*. Ele vai tentar transformar uma string de digitos em numero:

```
Number('0123'); // 123
Number('0123abc'); // NaN (aqui as letras estragam a conversão)
```

O `parseInt` é mais versátil e complexo. Ele procura converter os primeiros digitos até aparecer um caracter que não seja digito:

```
parseInt('0123'); // 123
parseInt('0123abc'); // 123
```

Assim ele faz parse (análise de numeros e não-numeros) e depois converte o tipo. [Mas têm algumas armadilhas.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123011/129) O `parseInt` aceita dois argumentos, pois permite converter *strings* em numeros com base decimal **ou não**. Vejamos este exemplo:

```
parseInt('0123abc'); // 123 - decimal
parseInt('0123abc', 8); // 83 - octal
parseInt('0123abc', 2); // 1 - binário
```

Assim pode dizer-se que a semântica é importante e o tipo de string também. Se só temos digitos e queremos um numero em base decimal o `Number` pode ser mais apropriado, por exemplo.

Em casos de notação com exponenciais, o parseInt vai falhar pois ele pára de analizar quando encontra letras em base decimal. Exemplo com `1000` em formato exponêncial `1e3`:

```
Number(1e3); // 1000 
Number('1e3'); // 1000 
parseInt('1e3'); // 1 (!errado!)
parseInt('1e3', 32); // 1475
```

O `Number` distingue-se também do `parseInt` noutro aspeto: o `parseInt` retornta `int`(ie *inteiros*), enquato que o `Number` retorna *numeros* com ou sem casa decimal, consoante a entrada:

```
Number('10.5'); // 10.5
parseInt('10.5'); // 10
```

Comment: Ótimo Sergio, também poderia falar dos numeros decimais, mas já vou lhe deixando o +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado, estava a completar e juntei tb exponenciais.

Comment: Está muito boa a resposta, vai ajudar muitas pessoas ;)

Comment: Deixo aqui uma dica, também é possível converter para int utilizando o operator `+` antes da string. Ou seja `+"12"`